# Setting folder for ASP.NET Core integration tests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two projects. One is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with the following structure.

```
MyApp.Web
  wwwroot
    (css, js folders etc.)
    Resources
      (production files)
```

I also have an integration test project.

```
MyApp.Web.IntegrationTests
  Resources
    (test files)
```

The integration test project contains a test class that extends `IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<MyApp.Web.Startup>>` and has its own `Resources` folder containing test files.

I would like to keep my test files in the integration test project, and for my web app to reference the integration test `Resources` folder when running integration tests. Of course, when running the web app normally, the web app should reference its own `Resources` folder.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to your web app running normally you can create a slightly different configuration in integration testing. Before passing IConfiguration to your WebHostBuilder configure it as you need.

If you want to use real `resources` in integration tests I would keep those files in web app project and reference them from integration tests project. As I don't know how you access those files I can't give you full answer but using this configuration it should quite easy to do this

```
public static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
{
    var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string appsettingsPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"../../../../WebApp.Api/"));
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .AddJsonFile(SettingsFileName, optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
         .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(appsettingsPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
         .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(appsettingsPath, "appsettings.Development.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
         .AddUserSecrets(UserSecretsId)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
         .Build();
    return config;
}
```

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseEnvironment("Development")
       .UseConfiguration(configuration)
       .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this is too long for a comment...

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In particular [mocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#inject-mock-services) and [path inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#how-the-test-infrastructure-infers-the-app-content-root-path) using [WebApplicationFactoryContentRootAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactorycontentrootattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I substituted a dependency as follows.

```
public class ReportsIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    public ReportsIntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
}

[Fact]
async Task CanGetReport()
{
    var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(
        builder =>
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.Remove(services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IResourcesPathProvider)));
            services.AddSingleton<IResourcesPathProvider, CustomResourcesPathProvider>();
        })).CreateClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync("/reports?dataSource=DataSource");

    // Checks and assertions...
}

public class CustomResourcesPathProvider : IResourcesPathProvider
{
    public string ResourcesFolder => "Resources";
}
```